# Update status in LinkedIn via simple URL

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm developing a web-app which is similar to stackoverflow. And I need to implement some "LinkedIn" button for each question/answer which should update user's status in LinkedIn to smth like "Reading: [title of a question] ([url to a question])".

I have found that request like

http://www.linkedin.com/status?statusText=Reading%20smth...&save=Save&revisionParam=2

does this, but... revisionParam must be equal current revisionParam+1, but I do not khow current value of revisionParam :(.

Can someone help me with whis?

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the homepage of the user, and read the the revisionParam from the page. The you can get he next revision that should be submitted

**Another option**

If you register to the linkedin API, there is an update status method, see [here](http://linkedin.mashery.com/page/Status_Updates)